# Is docker compose "environment" only evaluated at runtime (not when building the image)?

Tags: docker

I'm correcly passing the `TZ` env variable to my **php service**, infact I can print the variable and output it to a `timezone.ini` file:

```bash
/srv # echo $TZ
Europe/Rome
/srv # echo "date.timezone = $TZ" > ${PHP_INI_DIR}/conf.d/timezone.ini
/srv # cat ${PHP_INI_DIR}/conf.d/timezone.ini
date.timezone = Europe/Rome
/srv # date
Wed Mar 22 15:10:20 CET 2023
```

I want to do the same **during build time**. My `docker-compose.yml` file (stripped down):

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./
      target: php
    environment:
      TZ: ${TZ:-Europe/Rome}
```

In the `Dockerfile` I'm using `TZ`, but I think in a wrong way... or maybe I'm missing something because the content of `timezone.ini` doesn't contain the value (`TZ` empty):

```docker
FROM php:8-fpm-alpine as php
   
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata; \
    echo "date.timezone = $TZ" >> ${PHP_INI_DIR}/conf.d/timezone.ini
```

**I guess that `environment` is really something at runtime and the build process doesn't know about it... right? What could be the solution, apart from using an `ARG`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line pretty much exactly describes the situation: Compose `environment:` is only evaluated when the container is run and not when the image is build.  Dockerfile `ARG` and Compose `build: { args: }` is the most obvious workaround.

Still, it's reasonable to not want to "bake in" a time zone to an image when you build it; so how can you make a change in the container filesystem, before the main application starts up, based on an environment variable not known until run time?

I usually use an *entrypoint wrapper script* for this.  This setup uses a Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` to do the startup-time setup and then run the actual main container process, which is specified by Dockerfile `CMD`.

You're starting from the `php:fpm` image and inherit its default `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, so for this particular case you need to do a little archaeology.  Go to the [Docker Hub `php` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/php).  At the top is normally a section of `Dockerfile` links, though in this case it points at the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/php/README.md#supported-tags-and-respective-dockerfile-links).  Find `8-fpm-alpine` in that listing and read through its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/b486922583642fbe609b8153379ae2ce0256df51/8.2/alpine3.17/fpm/Dockerfile).  In particular, [at the end of the file](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/b486922583642fbe609b8153379ae2ce0256df51/8.2/alpine3.17/fpm/Dockerfile#L262), there is

```bash
# (no ENTRYPOINT)
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Let's write our own entrypoint script.  This just needs to do two things: write the `timezone.ini` file, and then `exec "$@"` to run the `CMD` (this is passed as arguments to the entrypoint script).

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

if [ -n "$TZ" ]; then
  echo "date.timezone = $TZ" >> ${PHP_INI_DIR}/conf.d/timezone.ini
fi

exec "$@"
```

If the base image had contained an `ENTRYPOINT`, you'd need to put that in the last line, with `exec` before it and `"$@"` after it, translating back from JSON-array syntax to Bourne shell syntax.

In the Dockerfile, you need to install the `tzdata` package and your script.  Set the `ENTRYPOINT` to run your script.  In the image as you have it now, you inherit the `CMD` from the base image, but setting `ENTRYPOINT` resets `CMD`, so you also need to repeat the base image's `CMD`.

```bash
FROM php:8-fpm-alpine
   
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
COPY entrypoint.sh ./           # may come along with a `COPY ./ ./` line
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]  # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

The two things to double-check are that the file is executable on your host (run `chmod +x entrypoint.sh` and commit that change to source control on a Linux or MacOS host), and if you're on a Windows host, it must have Unix-style LF-only line endings.

Comment: Thanks, I perfecly understand how you would solve it. But why do you think that baking the timezone in the image is a bad practice?

Comment: You don't usually want to recompile the image for basic configuration changes.  If you need to run the same program from a different location, you'd prefer to `docker run -e TZ=... the-same-image` without rebuilding anything.

Comment: Nice perfect example thanks